# How to Create an API which gives response in JSON format

Tags: android, rest, phpmyadmin

The website is already hosting on the server. I am trying to access data which is in PhpMyAdmin, into my android application.

Comment: Please post codes which you tried and getting an error, so the community can help you.

Comment: this question is very common, please try your self before create a new question, anw, welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: first, you need to create web service, using that web service display data in android. call web service using- https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use any of networking libraries in android like Volley , retrofit , okHttp ... etc and learn how to decode JSON format then use this decode by any of networking libraries ,
you can use this library https://square.github.io/retrofit/ 
or use this library https://developer.android.com/training/volley

Comment: I don't know how to decode JSON, I am trying PHP script as API to get data from the database.

Comment: you need to using PHP script that decode query if ( Select * from tablename ) to (json_encode) in PHP then using one of those libraries to decode this JSON format into android